# Is it possible to get the logged in username in a jquery script?

Tags: jquery, users

> How can I get the logged in username in a `jQuery` script?

#### Background:

I'm working with ACF repeater fields, and I want to auto populate a subfield **with the logged in username**. This should be executed each time the user adds a new row in the repeatable field.

Everything looks pretty well, but I'm stuck at the point of getting the logged in username in `jQuery`. I don't know how to get it. Any guidance will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you using this code in a `.js` file or a `.php` file ?

Comment: In a .js file, it is a jquery script

Comment: downvoted as I suspect that anything that have to do with ACF needs to remain in ACF land, and ACF is off-topic.Personally I think that If you need flexibility ACF is your enemy, not your friend.... anyway If by miracle there is a vanilla wordpress solution that satisfies this, give me a ping and I will remove the downvote.

Comment: @MarkKaplun forget about ACF, the main point of the question is to know how to access to some WP db data through js. It is independent of what plugin or function are you using... I'm used to achieve it coding php, but still a newbie when js is involved.

Comment: cool can you make some edit so I remove it, (if you care about it all)

Comment: @MarkKaplun In this case the fact ACF may be in play is irrelevant. `wp_localize_script()` should still work since all it does is create a JavaScript object and make it available for use in the script for which it is associated.

Comment: @belinus, sure but the question had too much focus on ACF, leading to an impression that an integration with ACF front end is required.

Comment: @MarkKaplun Your points were valid. I've edited the question now & looking at the accepted answer, this should now be on topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use the [`wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) function which allows you to create a JavaScript object, fill it with data using PHP, and then pass it into the JavaScript file.

This is done in your `functions.php` file inside the function where you're enqueuing your JavaScript file. You will need to pass it the handle you enqueue your script as, the name of the object you want to use in JavaScript, and an array of properties and values for the object.

From then on you just use the [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/wp_get_current_user) function to get your values.

For example:

```
function theme_scripts() {
   global $current_user;
   $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

   wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
   wp_localize_script( 'theme-script', 'theUser', array (
      'username' => $current_user->user_login,
   ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );
```

The thing is that `$current_user` is not populated by default in your enqueue function, so you're going to need to call it somewhere before hand as follows:

```
global $current_user;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

This object can now be accessed in your script with properties for every key you put in the array. So in this case you would access the user's login name as `theUser.username`.

Comment: Thank you @belinus It works like a charm! I didn't know about `wp_localize_script`, and it seems to be a lifesaver for a variety of situations that I had never known how to solve, thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. I did notice I forgot to add a bit to explain how to use the object so I edited it for future reference.

Comment: I think that in the wp_localize_script declaration, `theUser` should be passed between quotation marks `'theUser'`, if not, I got an warning error message ;)

Comment: why are you using the `$current_user` global instead of just saving the results of `wp_get_current_user()` into a local variable?

Comment: @shea When I was testing to make sure my answer worked, I dropped the `global` and it didn't work.